# Date(), Date.UTC() strange behavior with scope operator

Tags: javascript

Is that me doing something wrong or some known bug of using scope operator (`[...arr]`) with `Date()`/`Date.UTC()` constructor?

What confuses me:

```
x = [2015,5,1]; //(3) [2015, 5, 1]
new Date(2015, 5, 1); //Just as expected, Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
new Date([...x]); //Fri May 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
new Date(Date.UTC([...x])) //Invalid Date
```

p.s. I know, the latter is ambiguous, since `Date()` with more than 1 argument already returns UTC date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) parameter is not an array.

Remove the array like :

```js
x = [2015, 5, 1];
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(...x))
console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are passing the same array `x` as argument. Use [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). Because `Date.UTC` doesnot accept array as argument

> `UTC()` takes comma-delimited date and time parameters

```js
x = [2015,5,1]; //(3) [2015, 5, 1]
new Date(2015, 5, 1); //Just as expected, Mon Jun 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(...x)))
```